# How to add the Timezone the dateFromQuery and the parse string dd//

Tags: datetime, grails, timezone

I have a field that let me search some user by his created time. The problem is if the user don't have the GMT time, for example he has BDT, I can't find any user.

That I want to know is how can i add to the Timezone the dateFromQuery and the parse string dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z

Thanks in advance

This is the code to get the user time:

```
TimeZone tz = user.timeZone

        if(tz!=null) {
            params.timeZone = tz.getID()
        }
```

And this is the query that I'm trying but don't work:

```
if (params.dateFromQuery){
                TimeZone ta = params.date('dateFromQuery', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                ge('startTime', ta)
                params.dateFrom = ta
            }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to build a`criteria query`? Another thing `params.date()` returns an instance of `java.util.Date` so there is no way you can store it in a variable of type `java.util.TimeZone`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build a criteria query to the search